# How do I get value from superclass attribute?

Tags: swift

Suppose I have SuperClass and I want to get its attribute value to subclass

```
class Person {
   var name = String()

   init(name : String){
      self.name = name
   }
}

var JonSnow = Person(name : "Jon Snow")

class Ranger : Person {

    func getRangerName()->String {

       return "Ranger name is \(super.name)"

    }
    // I want to get name value from super class
}
```

How do I get name value directly from super class Without reinit the value in subclass ?

Comment: only a self.name in the children should do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by "Without reinit the value in subclass"? You mean you want to be able to initialise a `Ranger` without providing a name? You'll need to provide your own initialiser for that.

Comment: @harmish i want to get value directly from superclass which is "Jon Snow" in this case, is it posibble?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access it self.x

So using your code:

```
class Person {
    var name : String = "Jon Snow"
}

class Ranger : Person {

    func printName() {
        print(self.name)
    }

}
```

**Edit**

Here is a full working project with that example implemented: [download project](https://uploadfiles.io/37cbc31)

Comment: but when I declare Ranger class its keep asking for name parameter?

Comment: Maybe the error in your code come from somewhere else. I implemented an empty project that have only those classes. please check it out.